# Transferring value from php array to jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Array $data2 is used for making charts, it contains product names of my company. I want to assign the values in $data2 i.e product names to jquery array 'categories' instead of places listed in the code below...?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Product Selling Report'
        },


  <?php

  $sql="select productid,count(productid)as num from orderdetails group by productid order by num desc";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
   while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $rep=$arr['productid'];
    $sql2="select * from product where productid='$rep'";
    $res2=mysql_query($sql2);
    $arr2=mysql_fetch_array($res2);
    $data2[$i]=$arr2['productname'];
    $i=$i+1;
    }

     ?>
        xAxis: 
            categories: [
                'Tokyo',
                'Jakarta',
                'New York',
                'Seoul',
                'Manila',
                'Mumbai',
                'Sao Paulo',
                'Mexico City',
                'Buenos Aires',
                'Guangzhou',
                'Shenzhen',
                'Istanbul'
            ],
      },
      });
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. What is going wrong? What is the PHP actually rendering?

Comment: use JSON by json_encode in PHP and assign it as a dictionary variable in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Product Selling Report'
        },
        xAxis: 
            categories: [

  <?php

  $sql="select productid,count(productid)as num from orderdetails group by productid order by num desc";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
   while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $rep=$arr['productid'];
    $sql2="select * from product where productid='$rep'";
    $res2=mysql_query($sql2);
    $arr2=mysql_fetch_array($res2, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    echo "'".$arr2['productname']."',\n";
    }

     ?>
            ],
      },
      });
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: @JuanMendes, I fully agree.. and I'd never do this for my own code.. but please, have a quick look at the PHP code in the asker's post.. you'll know what I mean

Comment: I don't see what you mean? You don't think my answer will work?

Comment: @JuanMendes, of course your answer will work.. come on.. it's JSON, what I mean is from the way the code goes.. unnecessary variables and unnecessary SQL results, you can see that the asker is looking more for a quick n' dirty solution. It's bad practice, I know, but if it was for me I'd rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: Are you saying since the code is bad, you should not use json_encode? It's a lot quicker than what you suggested. No reason to teach a bad way just because the code is not perfect.

Comment: Dude, don't take it personal, I'm just saying this is not an optimal solution, warning the OP. Does your girlfriend also warn you when you do something in a less than ideal way?

Comment: from my first comment, I fully agreed with you.. I acknowledged it as bad practice, the asker saw your comment under my answer and we all moved on.. then you came back again to argue just for argument's sake. That's what she does!

Comment: thank you mr.adnan.shammout...its working properly..thank u so much

Comment: what is the use of "MYSQL_ASSOC"...?? i'm just a bgner..sry if its a foolish question

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() will return an array that has both associative and numeric keys, so every value will be stored two times, but since you're using keys like 'productname' you only need associative, so it's a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode($data2)` outputs valid code for an array/map in JS

```
 categories: <?= json_encode($data2) ?>,
```

Comment: "not working" without an explanation shows a lack of effort,  you need to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
xAxis: 
        categories: [
            <?php $str = "";
                  foreach($data2 as $data) {
                      $str .= $data.',';
                   }
                   $str = substr($str,0,-1);
                   echo $str;
        ],
  },
  });
```

});